# Can't import new costum fonts in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pdfmake

i have generated new costum fonts using this commande
`$ pdfmakefg ./my-fonts ./pdf/fonts/custom-fonts.js`. then i have added it in assets/fonts/
When i try to import ne costum fonts in angular component, i get this error

```
import pdfFonts from '../../../assets/fonts/custom-fonts';
```

> add-student.component.ts:27:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a
> declaration file for module '../../../assets/fonts/custom-fonts'.
> 'C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/students-prjt/prjct/src/assets/fonts/custom-fonts.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.

path of new costume fonts is correct.
i can't get over this error! any help please?

Comment: I'm not sure but try to add that js in scripts array on angular.json

Comment: i added it, "scripts": ["src/assets/fonts/custom-fonts-opensans.js"], but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

i solve it by doing these steps:

1 - add allowJs: true inside `tsconfig.json` file

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true, ...}
```

2 - add module.export at the end of `costume-font.js` file

```
module.exports = this.pdfMake.vfs;
```